# Is there any possibility to separate keyword if there are more than one in one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any possibility to separate keyword if there are more than one in one row. Its actually the data from a survey to know brand awareness.

For example if i have df like this:

df

```
ID                             Brand
1                              BMW
2                              VW-BMW-Audi
3                              Audi
4                              Mercedes-Audi
```

my desired output would be like this:

```
ID                             Brand
1                              BMW
2                              VW
2                              BMW
2                              Audi
3                              Audi
4                              Mercedes
4                              Audi
```

So I would like that `id` remain same for all the keywords which appear in same row as you can see in desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df = df.assign(Brand = df.Brand.str.split('-')).explode('Brand')
print(df)
   ID     Brand
0   1       BMW
1   2        VW
1   2       BMW
1   2      Audi
2   3      Audi
3   4  Mercedes
3   4      Audi
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
df["Brand"] = df["Brand"].apply(lambda x: x.split("-"))

print(df.explode("Brand"))
```